# Why did my roasted pumpkin soup smell foul and seem sour after only 1/2 day?

Tags: soup

I made 2 batches of roasted pumpkin soup and both went sour and smelt horrible within 1/2 day.  I am unsure why and am baffled as I have made soups heaps of times, but not this roasted pumpkin soup.

Comment: I did read this somewhere: "If you completely cover hot soup or stock, it will turn "sour". Always allow it to cool completely before you cover it firmly. And never cook, reheat, or simmer soup or stock with a lid completely covering the pot. Always leave the lid ajar a little bit. This kind of "souring" is purely taste-related, not a safety issue."

Comment: I also read that the process of roasting the pumpkin makes it go sour.  It has never happened to me with non-roasted pumpkin soup.

Comment: Was the soup alright when you made it? Did you put it in the fridge after it was made?

Comment: How exactly was the soup handled between the time it was made and when you discovered it was sour?  It sounds like simple spoilage, but that takes time.   You might also want to share the recipe, and anything you did differently this time versus previous times.

Answer (score -2):

Were there a lot of onions in the soup? My uncle was a chef and he said that you should never put onions in soup as it would add a sour flavour.

Comment: I am sorry, this does not pass the gut test; countless soups around the world include onions.  For example, French Onion Soup.

Comment: onions are essential